# How to override default plugins and use them to own buttons ckeditor

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I know this question is asked couple of places but no one fit into my requirements.

I want to use default ckeditors plugin to my own buttons and icons.

Lets say, I have some buttons and icon on them, now I want to give them controls of ckeditor to work like normal ckeditor.

Say, I have button B having some icon of B on it. Now, my question is that how can I make that button B work like same ckeditor plugin.

Means, how it can bold the text like we do in ckeditor?

Is there is any way to do it?

My some js files are as follow:

for text manipulation:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function (config) {
        config.toolbar = 'text';
        config.toolbar_text = [
            {name: 'basicstyles', groups: ['basicstyles', 'cleanup'], items: ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline']},
            {name: 'paragraph', items: ['JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight', 'JustifyBlock']},
            {name: 'colors', items: ['TextColor', 'BGColor']},
            {name: 'links', items: ['Link']},
            {name: 'styles', items: ['Styles', 'Format', 'Font', 'FontSize']}
        ];
        config.skin = 'bootstrapck';
    };
});
```

And here is my custom ckeditor file:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    CKEDITOR.disableAutoInline = true;

    $('.textEditor').click(function () {
        var element = $(this);
        //var editor = CKEDITOR.inline(this, {customConfig: 'text.js'});
        var editor = CKEDITOR.inline(this, {
            customConfig: 'text.js',
            extraPlugins: 'sharedspace',
            removePlugins: 'floatingspace,resize',
            sharedSpaces: {
                top: 'appendCkEditor',
            }
        });
        $('.saveText').on('click', function (evt) {
            //some operations
        });
    });
});
```

Now, what I want to have a custom button having B on it, and when user clicks on this B button, so the text gets BOLD, same for Italics and Underline.

Moreover, an more important part, Lets say, I have dropdown, with value align left, align center, align right, align justify.

So when user clicks on align right button from drop down it will align the text to right.

How to get this done whole process using ckeditor?

Comment: Wish to have Community right to invoke senior respectable users on unanswered question which remain unanswered for very very long time. don't know does SO do something for such question or no. cant believe how many unanswered question are still in queue for this tag.

Comment: Are you using https://github.com/tsechingho/ckeditor-rails ?

Comment: No I am using [https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor](https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor)